# Why is ChartJS combining two charts?

Tags: chart.js

I have the following Vue Template that uses ChartJS

```
<template>
  <div class="chart">
    <div>
      <canvas ref="cpu"> </canvas>
    </div>
    <div>
      <canvas ref="memory"> </canvas>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Chart from "./deps/Chart.bundle";
...
let ChartOptions = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'hour'
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                max: 45
            },
            stacked: true
        }]
    }
};
let ChartConfig =
{
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
      datasets: []
  },
  options: ChartOptions
};
export default {
    this.cpuChart = new Chart(this.$refs.cpu.getContext('2d'), ChartConfig);
    this.memoryChart = new Chart(this.$refs.memory.getContext('2d'), ChartConfig);
    ... 
    observable.subscribe(=>{
                 let cpu = col1.map(item=>{
                     return {
                         server: item.server,
                         t: item.time,
                         y: item.cpu
                     }
                 });
                 let memory = col1.map(item=>{
                     return {
                         server: item.server,
                         t: item.time,
                         y: item.memory
                     }
                 });
                 servers.forEach(server=>{
                     this.cpuChart.data.datasets.push({
                         label: server.name,
                         backgroundColor: dynamicColors(),
                         showLine: true,
                         data: cpu.filter(item =>{
                             return item.server === server.serverAddress
                         })
                     });
                     this.memoryChart.data.datasets.push({
                         label: server.name,
                         backgroundColor: dynamicColors(),
                         showLine: true,
                         data: memory.filter(item =>{
                             return item.server === server.serverAddress
                         })
                     });
                 });
                 this.cpuChart.update();
                 this.memoryChart.update();
    });
}
```

The problem is that when I run this both memory AND cpu are added to the cpuChart and nothing is added to the memory one. What I would like to happen is to have two entirely separate charts (one for each type). Can I have 2 Charts up at the same time using ChartJS?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed to create two individual instances per chart so I needed...

```
let ChartConfig = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
      datasets: []
  },
  options: ChartOptions
};
let ChartConfig2 = {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: {
        datasets: []
    },
    options: ChartOptions
};
...
this.cpuChart = new Chart(this.$refs.cpu.getContext('2d'), ChartConfig);
this.memoryChart = new Chart(this.$refs.memory.getContext('2d'), ChartConfig2);
```

I kinda see why but still feels kind of janky to me.